# Type/Namespace alias conventions in C#

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, namespaces, alias

Are there are any established naming or coding conventions for defining [namespace or type aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28VS.80%29.aspx) in C#?

For those who are unaware, the C# language has a feature where aliases can be defined local to a file for namespaces and types. This can be useful when there are naming conflicts with third party libraries as well as for shortening type names within your code. Below is an example of what it looks like.

```
using Forms = System.Windows.Forms;
```

Most of the examples that I've seen around the web tend to use unabbreviated capitalized names as aliases such as the alias **Forms** in the example above. In some places including the [official MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28VS.80%29.aspx) which explains example with an alias of **colAlias** for the namespace *System.Collections*. To make it more complicated there may be a preference for some to choose different guidelines depending on whether a namespace alias or a type alias is being defined.

In order to give some background for why I'm interested any guidelines with alias names I'll explain what I'm doing. In a recent project I began simplifying a pattern where I have several classes which inherit from a generic base class which accepts complex type arguments by using type aliases.

So using this technique the complex example below becomes the much more readable once type aliases are applied.

```
public class MyClass: MyGenericBaseClass<TripleLindyFancyAlgorithm<List<SomeValueType>>, List<SomeValueType>>
{
    public override List<SomeValueType> DoSomething(TripleLindyFancyAlgorithm<List<SomeValueType>> operation)
    {
        // ...
    }
 }
```

And below the must cleaner version using type aliases.

```
using Result = List<SomeValueType>;
using Algorithm = TripleLindyFancyAlgorithm<List<SomeValueType>>; // Note: cannot reference an alias within an alias definition!

public class MyClass: MyGenericBaseClass<Algorithm, Result>
{
    public override Result DoSomething(Algorithm operation)
    {
        // ...
    }
 }
```

Although this looks much more simplistic, it's easy to forget that an alias such as **Result** is actually just an alias for List and that there is no actual type called **Result**. In order to separate the concepts visually I'm considering following some prefixing convention similar to the use of underscore '_' before private members in order to help distinguish type aliases from actual types. Before I do so however I want to make sure that I'm not reinventing the wheel since maybe there already more established conventions out there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Namespace aliases are not a common feature of most code bases - the last place when I have used it, the senior developer was unfamiliar with it, though having worked with C# for many years.

Since it is rare, conventions have not been developed for it.

I would say that if you are going to use aliases, discuss this with your team to create your own convention.

Several different ways I have seen aliases used:

- An acronym of the namespace. Usually the capitals in the namespace.
- The very end of the namespace - if plural de-pluralized.
- A descriptive short name.

Comment: Great this is really the first post that discusses conventions which is what I originally set out to do by posing this question.

Comment: Awarded the bounty. Thanks for addressing the question that was asked (i.e. not just stating your own preference) and backing it up with real-world experience.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge - Thanks for that. As you say, the other answers do not seem to address the question at all but state personal preferences. The disparity in the answer also shows that there is indeed no consensus on conventions for namespace aliases...

Comment: I've also accepted your answer for the same reason that Mathew gave.

Answer (score 15):

I would only use aliases in the case of namespace conflict (i.e. only if I *had* to).

For me at least, any other use is just confusing and a distraction.

Comment: But you have to admit that in the example I gave, if you had to write 100+ plus similar classes which all had the same pattern that the type aliasing feature does dramatically improve the readability. Although I agree it can be confusing, I think in this type of example it is actually just as much if not more confusing to leave the complex example as is.

Comment: about the example - nesting generics that deep would almost never be necessary and if it is, it's a sign that the classes should be redesigned, rather than a sign an alias should be used.  that's just too confusing for mortals.

Comment: @Dave - A very valid point although to get into specifics of design I would have to divulge details of the actual code which prompted me to ask this question. For the sake of being productive, I'll try to guide focus less on how reasonable the example is and whether type alias should be used or not and more on conventions for type aliases in C# code.

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I would only use it to keep intelli-sense clean.

```
using StringBuilder = System.Text.StringBuilder;
```

If you rename types you open up Pandora's box for maintenance programmers.

Comment: While I agree that using this technique in cases where it isn't warranted would very bad for maintenance, I think the original complex example without any improvements is probably even more of a concern.

Comment: I may be crazy, but I think it is more readable when it is so explicit.

Comment: ChaosPandion, maybe your right. The main point however is to discuss naming conventions although I think it is important to consider coding guidelines with respect to the use of aliases.

Answer (score 4):

The two most common cases for namespace aliases are:

1. I saw it and I use it (as a trend)
2. I port code from another language

For the first case, no comment. For the second one a good example is porting code from C and use namespace aliases for practicality like:

```
using i64 = System.Int64;
using u8 = System.Byte;
using u32 = System.UInt32;
using u64 = System.UInt64;
```

Even if you consider the above aliases as lazy programming, they help to avoid mistakes.

Comment: Your code example is not namespace aliasing but type aliasing (both done with a `using` directive).

Comment: Right. Just like "using StringBuilder = System.Text.StringBuilder;" from ChaosPandion. My experience so far says that most of the people are thinking of it as namespace aliasing.

Comment: Most people probably use them interchangeable, if they use them at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think the people who are inclined toward not using them at all **are** giving the answer you asked for. That **is** the convention. This isn't to say that it can't be useful, but not using it remains the norm.

Comment: Fair assessment, please consider making a comment on somebody's answer or my original question though.

Comment: Why, while some of the others argue against using using, none say it is the answer to the question "Are there are any established naming or coding conventions for defining namespace or type aliases in C#?" I do :)

Comment: So I guess your answer is "no", if so that would be a simple and acceptable answer. Although it's apparent that from other peoples comments that there are some conventions although perhaps not very widespread or consistent.

Comment: No, my answer isn't "no conventions", it's "by convention, actively avoid it", which isn't quite the same.

Comment: Fair enough that will buy you and up-vote.

Answer (score 2):

You could adopt a convention to use them for abstraction.

```
using Id = System.Int32;
```

This way you can easily just replace that line with

```
using Id = System.Guid;
```

at some point and no other code would have to change (assuming you didn't peeked through the abstraction to create dependencies on the actual type...)

Comment: This works for simple types, but once you have a class or a generic there is some pain because the methods are rarely shared across those, except for very general cases such as ToString(). I tend to prefer doing this for the reason you list, anyway, though. It actually IMPROVES readability to specify a type that makes sense in the context in which it is used.

Answer (score 0):

I generally only use them when I need to use  two similarly named classes in different namespaces, and don't want to fully specify the type in the code:

```
using xItem = My.Project.NameSpace.Item;
using yItem = Your.ThirdParty.Framework.Item;
```